# C# List being treated as a pointer not a container of objects

Tags: c#, .net, list

I *think* I have figured out what is going on here, but I would like some confirmation. (code is at the bottom of the question)

I have a List object which I need to make a **copy** of.

The ways I have attempted this have been by creating another **new** List of the same type then using the '=' operand, I also tested with the AddRange method and got the same results.

No matter how I manipulate the copy of the List it applies the manipulations to the original as well.

I believe it is because C# is using lists as a reference/pointer structure rather than as object/value. Is this correct?

```
 temp1.AddRange(list1);
 temp2.AddRange(list2);


            foreach(record item in temp1)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> itemB in temp2.First().data)
                {
                    item.data.Add(itemB.Key, null);
                    ERRORDATA = "item data state:" + item.ToString() + "\r\nitemB key:[" + itemB.Key + "] " + itemB.Value;
                }
            }

temp1.First().data.Add("DOOBY", "doo");
```

after this executes, list1 has inserted the dooby,doo key/value pair when it *should* have only done that to the temp1 object.

cheers for any answers.

Comment: Yes, `List<T>` is a reference-type, not a value-type. Use `x.GetType().IsValueType` to determine if the object has value-type semantics. The major exception to this is `System.String` which is a reference-type that behaves with value-type semantics.

Comment: It would be very useful when you post code that you make it "copy-and-paste executable". Right now it's like a cryptic crossword clue.

Comment: Cheers for the confirmation, I figured it was something like that but wasn't 100% sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you are confusing a change to the "list" temp1 with a change to the objects held by each list. The objects held by each list are just references to the objects, so a change made to the object in one list will be reflected in the other lists.  However if you did a temp1.Add(o), o would not be added to temp2.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified I am using two different lists each of which has a copy made of it. changes to objects in temp1 affect the object in list1. So yeah you and Enigmativity were bang on.